# What is the difference between React functional component <Message id> and js function formatMessage() and which one is better to use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following code

Message Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const localizedMessages = {
   'title': 'This is my Title'
}

const Message = ({ id, ...params }) => {
  const msg = localizedMessages[id] || id;
  return <React.Fragment>{msg}</React.Fragment>;
};

export default Message;
```

And a util method formatMessage(plain javascript function):

```
const localizedMessages = {
   'title': 'This is my Title'
}

export function formatMessage(id, params) {
  return localizedMessages[id] || id;
}
```

And actual component where I want to use

```
import { Button, Dialog, DialogActions, DialogContent, DialogContentText, DialogTitle } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import Message from './Message';
import formatMessage from './utils';

const MyComponent = () => {

  return <Dialog
    open={true}
    keepMounted
    maxWidth="sm"
  >
    <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">
      <Message id="title" />
      {formatMessage('title')}
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
        {content}
      </DialogContentText>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button onClick={onClose} color="primary">
        <Message id="cancel" />
        {formatMessage('cancel')}
      </Button>
      <PrimaryButton onClick={onConfirmClick}>
        <Message id="yes" />
        {formatMessage('yes')}
      </PrimaryButton>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

either I can use < Message /> or formatMessage, both will do the work for me. I am more leaned towards < Message />.

**Note:** Removed code related to params from < Message /> and formatMessage() to avoid deviation from actual question. Params are used for interpolation.

Comment: @GalAbra, corrected the code. Please check. That is not actual, code how we import actual localized messages, for easy understanding I kept in same fiile.

Comment: Not much of a difference really, the component returns some text wrapped in a `Fragment`. You could `const Message = ({ id, ...params }) => localizedMessages[id] || id;` and it would return the exact same value.

Answer (score 0):

Your component doesn't include any additional functionality to the function's: they both just return plain text value by its key.

When that's the case, I don't see any reason to complicate the code and use a component.

Using a component not only suggests that you're having some sort of graphical-rendering or data-fetching taking place (which aren't in this case), but also makes your code more verbose and lengthy, which is usually a thing we try to avoid.
In your example you only use one argument, but this is much more distinct when you have more arguments:

```
<Message
  arg1={1}
  arg2={2}
  arg3={3}
/>
```

or

```
formatMessage(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I gave just small  example for better and quick understanding. <Message /> or formatMessage() is used across application, where ever we have display text.

Comment: Removed code related to params from <Message /> and formatMessage() to avoid deviation from actual question. Params are used for interpolation.